# Converting an if-else statement into a switch statement to make code more readable

Tags: java

I need a bit of help converting this code into a switch statement. I'm not used to using switch statements. I am trying to make my code more readable and shorter.

```
if (move.equals("D")) {
    if ((x + 1) == n) {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[0][y];
        magicSquare[0][y] = cache;
    } else {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x + 1][y];
        magicSquare[x + 1][y] = cache;
    }
} else if (move.equals("U")) {
    if ((x - 1) == -1) {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[n - 1][y];
        magicSquare[n - 1][y] = cache;
    } else {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x - 1][y];
        magicSquare[x - 1][y] = cache;
    }
} else if (move.equals("R")) {
    if ((y + 1) == n) {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x][0];
        magicSquare[x][0] = cache;
    } else {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x][y + 1];
        magicSquare[x][y + 1] = cache;
    }
} else if (move.equals("L")) {
    if ((y - 1) == -1) {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x][n - 1];
        magicSquare[x][y] = cache;
    } else {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x][y - 1];
        magicSquare[x][y] = cache;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to learn exactly how "switch statement" work and when to use it, programming is all about learning and practicing, getting the answer directly won't help you, here are some references (read and try first)
[Stackoverflow Question by zaynv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040706/converting-an-if-else-if-statement-into-a-switch-statement-in-java/19040783) 
[Great tutorial by codesdope](https://www.codesdope.com/java-decide-if-or-else/)

There are more resources ofc, just read and try simple examples then try on yours. after trying to convert if you face any issues, don't hesitate to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(move){
  case "D":
    if ((x + 1) == n) {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[0][y];
        magicSquare[0][y] = cache;
    } else {
        magicSquare[x][y] = magicSquare[x + 1][y];
        magicSquare[x + 1][y] = cache;
    }
  break;
  
  case "U":
    Your Code
  break;

  ...
}
```

You just have to give the switch a value. In the switch you just say for the Case "expected Value" do that and after the Case you make a break

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()` like this.

```
switch(variable_name){
   case "A":
          //your_work;
          break;
   case "B":
        //your_work;
        break;
   default:
      //always at the end. If you have something which will when the above 
      //options will not work then put it here
}
```

The values which are going to be checked are characters that's why I put`" "` if you have integer value you can simply use `1,2,3...`.
And do not forget to use `break` at the end of every `case` else it will run the next `case` statement.